# Different types of color adjectives

Tags: cross-linguistic, adjectives, colour-terms

One the one hand, Berlin and Kay found a linguistic hierarchy of colors. On the other hand, some languages have several kinds of colors.

In French, color adjectives are invariable if they come from nouns, e.g. *orange*, *marron* (brown).

In Japanese there are (in my view) four kinds of colors:

- four *i* adjectives (the older and 'purer' class of adjectives): 黒い (*kuroi*, black), 白い (*shiroi*, white), 赤い (*akai*, red), 青い (*aoi*, blue/green);
- three *kanji* representing colors but not directly *i* adjectives themselves: 黄 (*ki*, yellow), 紫 (*murasaki*, purple), 緑 (*midori*, green);
- words meaning explicitly 'the color of X': 茶色 (*chairo*, brown, lit. 'color of tea'), 灰色 (*haiiro*, grey, lit. 'color of ash'), 銀色 (*gin'iro*, 'color of silver'), etc. (possibly an open list);
- words coming from English: *pinku*, *orenji*, etc.

Are there other languages where there exist different grammatical classes of color adjectives?

Comment: Invariable orthographically speaking and not linguistically speaking.

Answer (score 6):

Much like Japanese, Swahili/Kiswahili has two classes of adjectives: the closed class of inflecting adjectives, and the open class of non-inflecting adjectives.

In the closed/inflecting class, there are only three color terms: red, white, and black. These are the three thought to be inherited from Proto-Bantu (and correspond nicely to Berlin and Kay's hierarchy).

All other color terms go in the open/non-inflecting class. Some of these are loanwords (*buluu* "blue", from English; *dhahabu* "golden", from Arabic), while others are nouns repurposed for their colors (*-a kijani* "green", literally "of the leaf"; *-a kijivu* "gray", literally "of ashes").